# Parsing a complex excel file using PHP Excel Library and retrieve data for email templates

Tags: php, excel, multidimensional-array

I want to parse the following excel file using PHP Excel Library and put the data into email templates(PFA).

[image: Reference Excel File]

Here goes the corresponding code for parsing the data:

```
//  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($target_file);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($target_file);
      } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
  }

    //  Get worksheet dimensions
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

    //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
        $val=array();
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumn; ++ $col) {
         $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
         $val[] = $cell->getValue();
        }
        //  Read a row of data into an array
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                        NULL,
                                        TRUE,
                                        FALSE);
        //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
        print_r(array_values($rowData));
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => S No [1] => Hotel Name [2] => Room Category [3] => GuestHouse Id [4] => Hotel Email [5] => City [6] => state [7] => 2nd Feb [8] => 3rd Feb [9] => 4th Feb [10] => 5th Feb [11] => 6th Feb [12] => 7th Feb [13] => 8th Feb [14] => 9th Feb [15] => 10th Feb [16] => 11th Feb [17] => 12th Feb [18] => 13th Feb [19] => 14th Feb [20] => 15th Feb ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Hotel 1 [2] => All [3] => 19 [4] => a@y.com [5] => Ahmedabad [6] => Gujarat [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Standard [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Superior [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Hotel 2 [2] => All [3] => 18 [4] => y@a.in [5] => Mumbai [6] => Maharashtra [7] => 2 [8] => 3 [9] => 4 [10] => 4 [11] => 4 [12] => 4 [13] => 4 [14] => 4 [15] => 4 [16] => 4 [17] => 4 [18] => 4 [19] => 2 [20] => 3 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Standard [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 0 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 [17] => 2 [18] => 2 [19] => 0 [20] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Superior [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 2 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 [17] => 2 [18] => 2 [19] => 2 [20] => 2 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => Hotel 3 [2] => All [3] => 199 [4] => m@mm.co.in [5] => Amravati [6] => Maharashtra [7] => 20 [8] => 20 [9] => 20 [10] => 20 [11] => 20 [12] => 20 [13] => 20 [14] => 20 [15] => 20 [16] => 20 [17] => 20 [18] => 20 [19] => 20 [20] => 20 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Standard [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 10 [8] => 10 [9] => 10 [10] => 10 [11] => 10 [12] => 10 [13] => 10 [14] => 10 [15] => 10 [16] => 10 [17] => 10 [18] => 10 [19] => 10 [20] => 10 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Superior [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 10 [8] => 10 [9] => 10 [10] => 10 [11] => 10 [12] => 10 [13] => 10 [14] => 10 [15] => 10 [16] => 10 [17] => 10 [18] => 10 [19] => 10 [20] => 10 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => Hotel 4 [2] => All [3] => 35 [4] => a@c.net [5] => Lonavala [6] => Maharashtra [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Villa [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 ) )
```

Now, what I want is after I have have this multi-dimensional associative array in place, I want to extract the data in such a way so as to get this expected output.

[image: Expected Output]

This is the place where I am stuck. I am unable to extract data properly because on one hand I need to skip empty null fields whereas on the other hand I need to skip the "All" field. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.